# I want to return a list of multiples values on excel

Tags: indexing, match, vlookup

I have a data sheet where I'd like to return a list of matches in a separate worksheet.

For example:-

```
CLIENT  VIEWS                       
Jones   5   10  76  120 138 144 163
Kivell  5   373 480             
Jardine 5   10  76  120 138 144 163
Gill    172 178 209 260 308 311 331
Sorvino 5   311 466 480 595
```

In a worksheet named "10", I'd like to show the following list:-

```
Jones
Jardine
```

I've done a fair bit of research and can't find a suitable formula anywhere.

Comment: What would you like to show exactly? The first cell of each row?

Comment: yes, the first cell of each row where the row contains "10". I would like them to be in a vertical list on a separate worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a vlookup, something along the lines of:

=vlookup([LookupValue],[TableYouAreLookingUpFrom],[ColumnIndexNumber],[RangleLookup])

1) For your Lookup value, you would use the name as your unique identifier that is being looked up. NOTE: This is not a good unique identifier, unless you don't have any duplicate names. A better unique identifier could be created by concatenating the clients first, last, and middle name (if available). You can do this by using an =concatenate function.

2) The Table you are looking up from would be the range of data you specified in your block of "code". You would have to set the Client name column (which you are using as your Lookup value) as the leftmost column, since a Vlookup always uses the leftmost value as it's lookup value.

3) Finally, the column Index Number Value is set to the numerical order value of whatever column you want to bring back. For example: If you want to bring back the value from the first "VIEWS" column (which looks like it contains all 5's), you would specify a Column Index Number of 2, which tells the function to bring back the value from the second column in your table, which we specified in step 2.

4) Finally, since you are just looking up one single value and not a range of values, you will set the [range_lookup] value to FALSE, because you are not looking up a range.

Hope this helps, good luck.